# Mongoose update subdocument of subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My schema definition as below. UserSchema has embedded Cards which in turn has many transactions..

```
var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
  merchantName: String,
  transactionTime: Date,
  latitude: Number,
  longitude: Number,
  amount: Number
});

var CardSchema = new Schema({
  cardIssuer: String,
  lastFour: String,
  expirationDate: String,
  transactions : [TransactionSchema]
});

/*
 * ...User Schema... 
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: String,
  salt: String,
  imageURL: String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  card: [CardSchema]
});
```

I want to add a transaction to the card already in the userschema but I am not sure how to do this in mongoose / mongodb

I identify the user and card as follows..

The api call goes through the auth middleware first

```
function isAuthenticated() {
  return compose()
    // Validate jwt
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
      if(req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
        req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
      }
      validateJwt(req, res, next);
    })
    // Attach user to request
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) return res.send(401);

        req.user = user;
        next();
      });
    });
}


// This is update based on Neil's answer below...
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  //var userItem = req.user;
  //console.log(userItem._id);
  //console.log(req.params.card);
  Transaction.create(req.body, function(err, transaction){
     console.log(transaction);
          //id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

          User.findOneAndUpdate({"card._id":id(req.params.card)},{ 
            // $set : {
            //   role: 'user1'
            // } ---- this update operation works!!
              "$push": {
                  "card.$.transactions": transaction
              } // -- this update operation causes error ...
          }, function(err,user) {
            // updated document here
            console.log('err' + err + " user " + user) ;
            return res.json(200, user);
        }
      )
    // }
   // })
})
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding new elements to an inner array is not difficult, as all you really need to do is match the position of the outer array to update in your query and then apply the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in the update portion.

```
var transaction; // and initialize as a new transaction

User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "card._id": cardId },
    { 
        "$push": {
            "card.$.transactions": transaction.toObject()
        }
    },
    function(err,user) {
        // updated document here
    }
)
```

So that is straightforward for [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operations. But be careful that you only ever want to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) as trying to update at a position of in "inner" array is not possible since the positional operator will only contain the **first** match, or the position in the "outer" array.

Comment: I m not sure but i get RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when I try the above code.

Comment: @gaurav Sounds like you are doing something inside a loop. Not sure what you are doing without posting code.

Comment: hi neil, I am not doing anything else in the loop. I had to change your answer to search by ObjectId() but I still get the same error. If I don't do the push operation I don't get the error.

Comment: @gaurav Add the code you are trying to your question so we can see what you are actually doing wrong.

Comment: @gaurav Try the `.toObject()` method to just get the plain object data rather than a mongoose document. That really should be implicitly called though. Same goes for the `_id` which really should be autocast from string by mongoose unless there is something overriding that not shown in the schema listing. May I ask is their some reason why you are both creating "transactions" in their own collection as well as embedding them? It's not that it's an invalid thing to do, just not usual.

Comment: toObject() worked - thanks so much.. As far as the question of transactions as seperate document well I guess I am just learning schema design :).. Thanks for the help and more.